# How to configure Wildfly to serve static content (like images)?

Tags: wildfly, undertow, static-content

I have a JavaEE application running on Wildfly 8.0.0 Final.

The application uses a lot of images and I don't want to store them in the database, so they are written to the hard disk.

How can I configure Wildfly/Undertow in order to serve these files (/var/images) on a certain URL, for example `http://localhost:8080/myapplication/imagesFromDisk`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Add another file handler and another location to the undertow subsystem in standalone.xml:

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        <location name="/img" handler="images"/>
    </host>
</server>
<handlers>
    <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content" directory-listing="true"/>
    <file name="images" path="/var/images" directory-listing="true"/>
</handlers>
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this using the CLI tool? I don't know how to access the handlers and filters nodes.

`/subsystem=undertow/filters:read-resource`
`Node path format is wrong around 'filters' (index=20).`

This doesn't work even if I want to read the filters. I see no mention of the filters and handlers in the documentation https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Undertow+%28web%29+subsystem+configuration as far as how to access them using CLI.

Comment: Do you know a way to achieve this in Jboss 7.1.1? Looking everywhere and nothing still.

Comment: @PawelPredki, launch CLI with the `--gui` option, there is a command builder. E.g. to add a filter: `/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/response-header=ie-disable-compatibility-header/:add(header-value=IE\=edge,header-name=X-UA-Compatible)`, then `/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=ie-disable-compatibility-header/:add`. The new filter won't work until the server is restarted though.

Comment: @hwellmann, how can I achieve this in pure Undertow? Do I really need to add a new handler just for files?
Also, why can't I just respond to the GET request with a image/jpeg type and the image in the body?
Thanks, I opened a question but no one replied yet. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023144/image-media-mime-type-responses-in-undertow)

Comment: Is it possibile to add columns sorting capabilities?

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't want to, or can't, [configure the Undertow subsystem](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Undertow+subsystem+configuration) in `standalone.xml`, then you need to make it work within the `.war`. For that, you may use a servlet to serve the files. There are few implementations around, the most famous (or highest on Google) is [by BalusC](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html). That one is licensed under LGPL, though. So I took the `DefaultServlet` and [made it more easily extensible](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/pull/374/files), so you can feed it the right Undertow `Resource`, e.g. [from a file system](https://github.com/OndraZizka/windup-web/blob/8db5c1a9d5e2c9c66d955f7519f5e5f55f458ccb/services/src/main/java/org/jboss/windup/web/fileservlet/FileDefaultServlet.java).

Theoretically, some servlet in Undertow should be able to serve from a filesystem, too, but the [`DefaultServlet`](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/handlers/DefaultServlet.java) code seems to only count with resources within a deployment.

Base class:

```
 /*
 * JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
 * Copyright 2014 Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
 * as indicated by the @author tags.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */
package io.undertow.servlet.handlers;

import io.undertow.io.IoCallback;
import io.undertow.io.Sender;
import io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.DirectoryUtils;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.RangeAwareResource;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.Resource;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.ResourceManager;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.DefaultServletConfig;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.Deployment;
import io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl;
import io.undertow.util.ByteRange;
import io.undertow.util.CanonicalPathUtils;
import io.undertow.util.DateUtils;
import io.undertow.util.ETag;
import io.undertow.util.ETagUtils;
import io.undertow.util.Headers;
import io.undertow.util.Methods;
import io.undertow.util.StatusCodes;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Abstract default servlet implementation for serving static content.
 * This is both a handler and a servlet. If no filters
 * match the current path then the content will be served up asynchronously using the
 * {@link io.undertow.server.HttpHandler#handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange)} method,
 * otherwise the request is handled as a normal servlet request.
 * <p>
 * By default we only allow a restricted set of extensions.
 * <p>
 *
 * @author Stuart Douglas
 * @author Ondrej Zizka, zizka at seznam.cz
 */
public abstract class DefaultServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String DIRECTORY_LISTING = "directory-listing";
    public static final String DEFAULT_ALLOWED = "default-allowed";
    public static final String ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = "allowed-extensions";
    public static final String DISALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = "disallowed-extensions";
    public static final String RESOLVE_AGAINST_CONTEXT_ROOT = "resolve-against-context-root";

    private static final Set<String> DEFAULT_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
        "js", "css", "png", "jpg", "gif", "html", "htm", "txt", "pdf", "jpeg", "xml",
        "svg", "ttf", "java")));

    private Deployment deployment;
    private ResourceManager resourceManager;

    private final Settings settings = new Settings();

    public Settings getSettings() {
    return settings;
    }



    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    ServletContextImpl sc = (ServletContextImpl) config.getServletContext();
    this.deployment = sc.getDeployment();

    // Settings from the servlet init parameters.
    if (config.getInitParameter(DEFAULT_ALLOWED) != null) {
        settings.defaultAllowed = Boolean.parseBoolean(config.getInitParameter(DEFAULT_ALLOWED));
    }
    if (config.getInitParameter(ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS) != null) {
        String extensions = config.getInitParameter(ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS);
        settings.allowed = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(extensions.split(",")));
    }
    if (config.getInitParameter(DISALLOWED_EXTENSIONS) != null) {
        String extensions = config.getInitParameter(DISALLOWED_EXTENSIONS);
        settings.disallowed = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(extensions.split(",")));
    }
    if (config.getInitParameter(RESOLVE_AGAINST_CONTEXT_ROOT) != null) {
        settings.resolveAgainstContextRoot = Boolean.parseBoolean(config.getInitParameter(RESOLVE_AGAINST_CONTEXT_ROOT));
    }

    String listings = config.getInitParameter(DIRECTORY_LISTING);
    if (Boolean.valueOf(listings)) {
        settings.directoryListingEnabled = true;
    }

    // Settings from the deployment configuration.
    DefaultServletConfig defaultServletConfig = getDeployment().getDeploymentInfo().getDefaultServletConfig();
    if (defaultServletConfig != null) {
        getSettings().setDefaultAllowed(defaultServletConfig.isDefaultAllowed());
        getSettings().setAllowed(new HashSet<>());
        if (defaultServletConfig.getAllowed() != null) {
            getSettings().getAllowed().addAll(defaultServletConfig.getAllowed());
        }
        getSettings().setDisallowed(new HashSet<>());
        if (defaultServletConfig.getDisallowed() != null) {
            getSettings().getDisallowed().addAll(defaultServletConfig.getDisallowed());
        }
    }

    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = getPath(req);
    if (!isAllowed(path, req.getDispatcherType())) {
        resp.sendError(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND);
        return;
    }
    if(File.separatorChar != '/') {
        //if the separator char is not / we want to replace it with a / and canonicalise
        path = CanonicalPathUtils.canonicalize(path.replace(File.separatorChar, '/'));
    }

    final Resource resource;
    //we want to disallow windows characters in the path
    if(File.separatorChar == '/' || !path.contains(File.separator)) {
        resource = resourceManager.getResource(path);
    } else {
        resource = null;
    }

    if (resource == null) {
        if (req.getDispatcherType() == DispatcherType.INCLUDE) {
            //servlet 9.3
            throw new FileNotFoundException(path);
        } else {
            resp.sendError(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Directory
    if (resource.isDirectory()) {
        if (!settings.directoryListingEnabled)
            resp.sendError(StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN);

        //  /servlet-name/some/dir/?css or ?js
        if ("css".equals(req.getQueryString())) {
            resp.setContentType("text/css");
            resp.getWriter().write(DirectoryUtils.Blobs.FILE_CSS);
            return;
        } else if ("js".equals(req.getQueryString())) {
            resp.setContentType("application/javascript");
            resp.getWriter().write(DirectoryUtils.Blobs.FILE_JS);
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder output = DirectoryUtils.renderDirectoryListing(req.getRequestURI(), resource);
        resp.getWriter().write(output.toString());
    }

    // File
    else {
        if(path.endsWith("/")) {
            //UNDERTOW-432
            resp.sendError(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }
        serveFileBlocking(req, resp, resource);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    /*
     * Where a servlet has received a POST request we still require the capability to include static content.
     */
    switch (req.getDispatcherType()) {
        case INCLUDE:
        case FORWARD:
        case ERROR:
            doGet(req, resp);
            break;
        default:
            super.doPost(req, resp);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    switch (req.getDispatcherType()) {
        case INCLUDE:
        case FORWARD:
        case ERROR:
            doGet(req, resp);
            break;
        default:
            super.doPut(req, resp);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    switch (req.getDispatcherType()) {
        case INCLUDE:
        case FORWARD:
        case ERROR:
            doGet(req, resp);
            break;
        default:
            super.doDelete(req, resp);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    switch (req.getDispatcherType()) {
        case INCLUDE:
        case FORWARD:
        case ERROR:
            doGet(req, resp);
            break;
        default:
            super.doOptions(req, resp);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doTrace(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    switch (req.getDispatcherType()) {
        case INCLUDE:
        case FORWARD:
        case ERROR:
            doGet(req, resp);
            break;
        default:
            super.doTrace(req, resp);
    }
    }

    protected void serveFileBlocking(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp, final Resource resource) throws IOException {
    final ETag etag = resource.getETag();
    final Date lastModified = resource.getLastModified();
    if(req.getDispatcherType() != DispatcherType.INCLUDE) {
        if (!ETagUtils.handleIfMatch(req.getHeader(Headers.IF_MATCH_STRING), etag, false) ||
                !DateUtils.handleIfUnmodifiedSince(req.getHeader(Headers.IF_UNMODIFIED_SINCE_STRING), lastModified)) {
            resp.setStatus(StatusCodes.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
            return;
        }
        if (!ETagUtils.handleIfNoneMatch(req.getHeader(Headers.IF_NONE_MATCH_STRING), etag, true) ||
                !DateUtils.handleIfModifiedSince(req.getHeader(Headers.IF_MODIFIED_SINCE_STRING), lastModified)) {
            resp.setStatus(StatusCodes.NOT_MODIFIED);
            return;
        }
    }

    //we are going to proceed. Set the appropriate headers
    if(resp.getContentType() == null) {
        if(!resource.isDirectory()) {
            final String contentType = deployment.getServletContext().getMimeType(resource.getName());
            if (contentType != null) {
                resp.setContentType(contentType);
            } else {
                resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            }
        }
    }
    if (lastModified != null) {
        resp.setHeader(Headers.LAST_MODIFIED_STRING, resource.getLastModifiedString());
    }
    if (etag != null) {
        resp.setHeader(Headers.ETAG_STRING, etag.toString());
    }
    ByteRange range = null;
    long start = -1, end = -1;
    try {
        //only set the content length if we are using a stream
        //if we are using a writer who knows what the length will end up being
        //todo: if someone installs a filter this can cause problems
        //not sure how best to deal with this
        //we also can't deal with range requests if a writer is in use
        Long contentLength = resource.getContentLength();
        if (contentLength != null) {
            resp.getOutputStream();
            if(contentLength > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                resp.setContentLengthLong(contentLength);
            } else {
                resp.setContentLength(contentLength.intValue());
            }
            if(resource instanceof RangeAwareResource && ((RangeAwareResource)resource).isRangeSupported()) {
                //TODO: figure out what to do with the content encoded resource manager
                range = ByteRange.parse(req.getHeader(Headers.RANGE_STRING));
                if(range != null && range.getRanges() == 1) {
                    start = range.getStart(0);
                    end = range.getEnd(0);
                    if(start == -1 ) {
                        //suffix range
                        long toWrite = end;
                        if(toWrite >= 0) {
                            if(toWrite > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                                resp.setContentLengthLong(toWrite);
                            } else {
                                resp.setContentLength((int)toWrite);
                            }
                        } else {
                            //ignore the range request
                            range = null;
                        }
                        start = contentLength - end;
                        end = contentLength;
                    } else if(end == -1) {
                        //prefix range
                        long toWrite = contentLength - start;
                        if(toWrite >= 0) {
                            if(toWrite > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                                resp.setContentLengthLong(toWrite);
                            } else {
                                resp.setContentLength((int)toWrite);
                            }
                        } else {
                            //ignore the range request
                            range = null;
                        }
                        end = contentLength;
                    } else {
                        long toWrite = end - start + 1;
                        if(toWrite > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                            resp.setContentLengthLong(toWrite);
                        } else {
                            resp.setContentLength((int)toWrite);
                        }
                    }
                    if(range != null) {
                        resp.setStatus(StatusCodes.PARTIAL_CONTENT);
                        resp.setHeader(Headers.CONTENT_RANGE_STRING, range.getStart(0) + "-" + range.getEnd(0) + "/" + contentLength);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    }
    final boolean include = req.getDispatcherType() == DispatcherType.INCLUDE;
    if (!req.getMethod().equals(Methods.HEAD_STRING)) {
        HttpServerExchange exchange = SecurityActions.requireCurrentServletRequestContext().getOriginalRequest().getExchange();
        if(range == null) {
            resource.serve(exchange.getResponseSender(), exchange, completionCallback(include));
        } else {
            ((RangeAwareResource)resource).serveRange(exchange.getResponseSender(), exchange, start, end, completionCallback(include));
        }
    }
    }

    private IoCallback completionCallback(final boolean include) {
    return new IoCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(final HttpServerExchange exchange, final Sender sender) {
            if (!include) {
                sender.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(final HttpServerExchange exchange, final Sender sender, final IOException exception) {
            //not much we can do here, the connection is broken
            sender.close();
        }
    };
    }

    /**
     * Returns the canonicalized URL path.
     */
    private String getPath(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    String servletPath;
    String pathInfo;

    if (request.getDispatcherType() == DispatcherType.INCLUDE && request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.INCLUDE_REQUEST_URI) != null) {
        pathInfo = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.INCLUDE_PATH_INFO);
        servletPath = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.INCLUDE_SERVLET_PATH);
    } else {
        pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
        servletPath = request.getServletPath();
    }
    String result = pathInfo;
    if (result == null) {
        result = servletPath;
    } else if(settings.resolveAgainstContextRoot) {
        result = servletPath + CanonicalPathUtils.canonicalize(pathInfo);
    } else {
        result = CanonicalPathUtils.canonicalize(result);
    }
    if ((result == null) || (result.equals(""))) {
        result = "/";
    }
    return result;

    }

    /**
     * @return true if the resource at the given path is allowed to be sent to the client.
     */
    protected boolean isAllowed(String path, DispatcherType dispatcherType) {
    int pos = path.lastIndexOf('/');
    final String lastSegment;
    if (pos == -1) {
        lastSegment = path;
    } else {
        lastSegment = path.substring(pos + 1);
    }
    if (lastSegment.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    int ext = lastSegment.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (ext == -1) {
        //no extension
        return true;
    }
    final String extension = lastSegment.substring(ext + 1, lastSegment.length());
    if (settings.defaultAllowed) {
        return !settings.disallowed.contains(extension);
    } else {
        return settings.allowed.contains(extension);
    }
    }

    public boolean isDirectoryListingEnabled() {
    return settings.directoryListingEnabled;
    }


    public void setDirectoryListingEnabled(boolean directoryListingEnabled) {
    settings.directoryListingEnabled = directoryListingEnabled;
    }

    public ResourceManager getResourceManager() {
    return resourceManager;
    }


    public void setResourceManager(ResourceManager resourceManager) {
    this.resourceManager = resourceManager;
    }


    public Deployment getDeployment() {
    return deployment;
    }




    protected static class Settings
    {
    private boolean directoryListingEnabled = false;
    private boolean defaultAllowed = true;
    private Set<String> allowed = DEFAULT_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS;
    private Set<String> disallowed = Collections.emptySet();
    private boolean resolveAgainstContextRoot;


    public boolean isDirectoryListingEnabled() {
        return directoryListingEnabled;
    }

    public void setDirectoryListingEnabled(boolean directoryListingEnabled) {
        this.directoryListingEnabled = directoryListingEnabled;
    }

    public boolean isDefaultAllowed() {
        return defaultAllowed;
    }

    public void setDefaultAllowed(boolean defaultAllowed) {
        this.defaultAllowed = defaultAllowed;
    }

    public Set<String> getAllowed() {
        return allowed;
    }

    public void setAllowed(Set<String> allowed) {
        this.allowed = allowed;
    }

    public Set<String> getDisallowed() {
        return disallowed;
    }

    public void setDisallowed(Set<String> disallowed) {
        this.disallowed = disallowed;
    }

    public boolean isResolveAgainstContextRoot() {
        return resolveAgainstContextRoot;
    }

    public void setResolveAgainstContextRoot(boolean resolveAgainstContextRoot) {
        this.resolveAgainstContextRoot = resolveAgainstContextRoot;
    }
    }
}
```

The [file serving servlet](https://github.com/OndraZizka/windup-web/blob/8db5c1a9d5e2c9c66d955f7519f5e5f55f458ccb/services/src/main/java/org/jboss/windup/web/fileservlet/FileDefaultServlet.java) (the one you will use in `web.xml`):

```
/*
 * JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
 * Copyright 2014 Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
 * as indicated by the @author tags.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */
package org.jboss.windup.web.fileservlet;

import io.undertow.Undertow;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.FileResourceManager;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.File;
import org.jboss.windup.web.addons.websupport.WebPathUtil;

/**
 * Default servlet responsible for serving up files from a directory.
 * This is both a handler and a servlet. If no filters
 * match the current path, then the resources will be served up asynchronously using the
 * {@link io.undertow.server.HttpHandler#handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange)} method,
 * otherwise the request is handled as a normal servlet request.
 *
 * <p>
 * By default we only allow a restricted set of extensions.
 * <p>

 * @author Ondrej Zizka, zizka at seznam.cz
 * @see Undertow's DefaultServlet
 */
public class FileDefaultServlet extends DefaultServlet
{
    public static final String BASE_PATH = "base-path";

    /**
     * Which directory should this servlet serve files from.
     */
    private String basePath;


    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    initBasePath();
    this.setResourceManager(new FileResourceManager(new File(basePath), 8*1024));
    }


    private void initBasePath() throws ServletException
    {
    // Get base path (path to get all resources from) as init parameter.
    this.basePath = getInitParameter(BASE_PATH);
    this.basePath = WebPathUtil.expandVariables(this.basePath);

    // Validate base path.
    if (this.basePath == null) {
        throw new ServletException("FileServlet init param 'basePath' is required.");
    } else {
        File path = new File(this.basePath);
        if (!path.exists()) {
            throw new ServletException("FileServlet init param 'basePath' value '"
                    + this.basePath + "' does actually not exist in file system.");
        } else if (!path.isDirectory()) {
            throw new ServletException("FileServlet init param 'basePath' value '"
                    + this.basePath + "' is actually not a directory in file system.");
        } else if (!path.canRead()) {
            throw new ServletException("FileServlet init param 'basePath' value '"
                    + this.basePath + "' is actually not readable in file system.");
        }
    }
    }

}
```

And here's a servlet which works like the previous `DefaultServlet` - that is, serving from the deployment.

```
/*
 * JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
 * Copyright 2014 Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
 * as indicated by the @author tags.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */
package io.undertow.servlet.handlers;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

/**
 * Default servlet responsible for serving up resources. This is both a handler and a servlet. If no filters
 * match the current path then the resources will be served up asynchronously using the
 * {@link io.undertow.server.HttpHandler#handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange)} method,
 * otherwise the request is handled as a normal servlet request.
 * <p>
 * By default we only allow a restricted set of extensions.
 * <p>
 * todo: this thing needs a lot more work. In particular:
 * - caching for blocking requests
 * - correct mime type
 * - range/last-modified and other headers to be handled properly
 * - head requests
 * - and probably heaps of other things
 *
 * @author Ondrej Zizka, zizka at seznam.cz
 */
public class ResourceDefaultServlet extends DefaultServlet {

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    this.setResourceManager(getDeployment().getDeploymentInfo().getResourceManager());
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isAllowed(String path, DispatcherType dispatcherType) {

    if (!path.isEmpty()) {
        if(dispatcherType == DispatcherType.REQUEST) {
            //WFLY-3543 allow the dispatcher to access stuff in web-inf and meta inf
            if (path.startsWith("/META-INF") ||
                    path.startsWith("META-INF") ||
                    path.startsWith("/WEB-INF") ||
                    path.startsWith("WEB-INF")) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return super.isAllowed(path, dispatcherType);
    }

}
```