# Image/Media MIME type responses in Undertow

Tags: java, undertow

I've been struggling trying to find a way to deliver .jpeg, .png or other contents in Undertow. Sending byte[] won't work and since Undertow is Non-blocking, I don't want to write the file on the output by doing the usual:

```
exchange.getOutputStream().write(myFileByteArray);
```

Is there any other way I can achieve it? I also encoded the image in Base64 using Undertow's default Base64 library, but didn't work either.

Edit: providing some code:
This is my method that encodes a file. It works for .js, .html and other text files, but not for images. The encoding is working, though, so my question is if I'm doing something wrong when sending it back to the person who requested.

This how I'm responding: (hardcoded for stackoverflow purposes)

```
exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
exchange.getResponseSender().send(getResource(resource, true));
```

**I'm not getting any exception on the undertow side. Image just won't show up on the browser. The browser says it can't decode the image..**

Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue? That is what error you are getting and what is your code?

Comment: ok, I'll provide some. hold on

Comment: Can you share the response headers you are getting for this image request?

Comment: Will this work? http://imgur.com/3uUsttM

Comment: Yes basically i am trying to see that your response header shows the base64 info. It is not showing in your shared url.

Comment: Chrome says response has no data available http://imgur.com/0mCLHYB

Comment: Ok that might be the real reason.

Comment: You can also use Firebug in firefox to analyze the response.

Comment: Well, but the thing is.. I'm actually sending the content just as I'm doing with the other resources (html, js, etc.). The output of the readFile function is a string indeed... =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of work wondering if my MIME configuration was right, I actually found out that you only need to write the file to the OutputStream of the exchange object.

Here's what I did:

```
if(!needsBuffering){
    exchange.getResponseSender().send(getResource(resource));
}else{
    exchange.startBlocking();
    writeToOutputStream(resource, exchange.getOutputStream());
}
```

...

```
private void writeToOutputStream(String resource, OutputStream oos) throws Exception {

    File f = new File(this.definePathToPublicResources() + resource);

    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

    int c = 0;

    while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
        oos.write(buf, 0, c);
        oos.flush();
    }

    oos.close();
    is.close();

}
```

Comment: Where does `needsBuffering` come from?