# Map image folder to Spring MVC and Wildfly

Tags: spring-mvc, wildfly

I have a Spring MVC app that is generally an image viewer that runs on Wildfly.

Images are created dinamically and are saved into nginx folder `/usr/share/nginx/html/images`.

How could I map Spring MVC app with that folder to be able to load images from it eg. map the folder to `localhost:8080/mySpringApp/images`?

Answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684037/how-to-configure-wildfly-to-serve-static-content-like-images) should be the way to go but the standalone.xml is always **overwritten** when starting the app from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the spring-mvc route all the way. When you are configuring the mappings for your static resources as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

You can state a file system location e.g.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:////usr/share/nginx/html/images/");
```

or configure based on the XML equivalent

Comment: Perfect. I've overlooked the `file:` autocomplete for the location attribute in the XML.

Comment: Great. Glad it helped