# How to configure Wildfly to serve static content (like images) with some authentification?

Tags: authentication, wildfly, undertow, static-content

Undertow 4 in Wildfly 10 can add some kind of authentication to limit the access to static resources:

Example:

```
http://localhost/img/my_img.jpg -> will return will return 401 Forbidden
http://localhost/img/my_img.jpg&auth=some_app_key -> will return 200 OK
http://localhost/img/my_img.jpg -> with a valid header parameter will return 200 OK
```

For serving static content this is a good example : [How to configure Wildfly to serve static content (like images)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684037/how-to-configure-wildfly-to-serve-static-content-like-images?rq=1)